# Disable/suppress warning CS0649 in C# for a specific field of class

Tags: c#, suppress-warnings

I have some fields in a C# class which I initialize using reflection. The compiler shows CS0649 warning for them:

> Field `foo' is never assigned to, and will always have its default
>   value`null' (CS0649) (Assembly-CSharp)

I'd like to disable the warning for these specific fields only and still let the warning be shown for other classes and other fields of this class.
It is possible to disable CS0649 for the whole project, is there anything more fine-grained?

Answer (score 104, accepted):

You could use [`#pragma warning`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/441722ys%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to disable and then re-enable particular warnings:

```
public class MyClass
{
    #pragma warning disable 0649

    // field declarations for which to disable warning
    private object foo;

    #pragma warning restore 0649

    // rest of class
}
```

Refer to [Suppressing “is never used” and “is never assigned to” warnings in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3821035/1149773) for an expanded answer.

Comment: Isn't the leading zero required?

Comment: @SeToY: Actually, no, they're not required.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that. That's why I've added the question mark next to my sentence :P

Comment: I updated my answer to play it safe while I checked. No harm either way :-)

Answer (score 18):

I believe it's worth noting the warning can also be suppressed by using inline initialization. This clutters your code much less.

```
public class MyClass
{
    // field declarations for which to disable warning
    private object foo = null;

    // rest of class
}
```

Comment: also another way to do the same is with `default`;
`private object foo = default;`

Answer (score 10):

```
//disable warning here
#pragma warning disable 0649

 //foo field declaration

//restore warning to previous state after
#pragma warning restore 0649
```

Answer (score 6):

```
public class YouClass
{
#pragma warning disable 649
    string foo;
#pragma warning restore 649
}
```

Comment: What does your answer add to the questions solution that hasn't been posted 5 minutes ago?

Comment: He probably just didn't see the first answer. Thanks anyway:)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to **disable ALL warnings** in the project (rather than per script) then do this:

Ceate a text file called mcs.rsp (for editor scripts) in your YOUR_PROJECT_NAME/Assets directory with contents (for example):

-nowarn:0649

(You can change the number to match whatever warning you want)

[Original answer](http://answers.unity.com/answers/1106962/view.html)

Note: This doesn't disable the warnings in the Unity console if you are using Unity (I am still investigating how to remove those)

Here is some [Unity documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PlatformDependentCompilation.html) with more information

Comment: If you name the file csc.rsp it works for the unity console.

Comment: I just noticed this I will try it!