# Writing comments for C# pre-processors?

Tags: c#, comments, preprocessor

I'm writing on a script for Unity 3D and have/want to use some pre-processors.

For example VisualStudio always throughs some warnings such as

> Field 'foo' is never assigned to, and will always have its default
> value 'null' (CS0649) (Assembly-CSharp)

for a code like

```
puclic class Example : MonoBehvaiour
{
    [SerializedField]
    private GameObject exampleObject;

    ...
}
```

though the field ofcourse will be set within the Inspector of the Unity Editor.

Additionally I never use the field **in this class** but have written a [CustomEditor](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/editor-CustomEditors.html) where the field is needed. So I also would get some other warnings something like

> variable declared but not used.
>
> variable assigned but not used.
>
> private field assigned but not used.

So after making sure that the code is correct and those warnings unneccesary I decided to follow [this](https://answers.unity.com/questions/21796/disable-warning-messages.html) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13726743/disable-suppress-warning-cs0649-in-c-sharp-for-a-specific-field-of-class) and used some pre-processors e.g.

```
#pragma warning disable 0414
#pragma warning disable 0649

    // some fields here

#pragma warning restore 0414
#pragma warning restore 0649
```

---

So now to my question:

And **how could I add comments for pre-processors?**

It's a pity there is not just something like

```
#comment "some comment here"
```

This seems not really intended/thought about but I would really like to do it in order to let my collegues know what the pre-processors are good/used for.

---

Ofcourse I could just add the comments but they are not intended with the pre-processors but with the normal code as e.g.

```
    // This silences "private field assigned but not used." warnings
#pragma warning disable 0414

    // flag to look for unsaved changes
    private bool _unsavedChanges = false;

    // This re-enables "private field assigned but not used" warnings
#pragma warning restore 0414
```

this makes it look very cluttered instead of clarify things and the comments don't seem to refer/"belong" to the pre-processors but the normal code instead.

The alternative would be inline comments which for now come closest to it I guess

```
#pragma warning disable 0414 // This silences "private field assigned but not used." warnings

    // flag to look for unsaved changes
    private bool _unsavedChanges = false;

#pragma warning restore 0414 // This re-enables "private field assigned but not used" warnings
```

---

Note:
I do not want to just disable warnings in general for the file or project!

 And these examples are not the only pre-processors I'ld like to add comments for.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Custom Compiler Warnings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154109/custom-compiler-warnings)

Comment: Comments should never be seen as clutter. They assist future developers that come in behind you to maintain your code.

Comment: @davisj1691 please see my comment on your Answer .. this is not what I'm looking for. I don't want to add a custom **warning** but instead a **comment** which explained that my pre-processor **disabled** some warnings

Comment: Why not just use a normal comment? It may look cluttered, but the better the documentation, the easier it is for someone with no knowledge of your code to maintain.

Comment: @davisj1691 Because as I mentioned already it makes it look very strange since normal comments have a "wrong" indentation and don't seem to refer to the pre-processor. Especially in some `#if... #else... #endif` blocks it doesn't really make things better understandable

Comment: Well there aren't any [preprocessing directives](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives/) that handle comments, you could always remove the indentation manually.

Comment: @davisj1691 it will always be re-intended by VisualStudio automatically together with all other lines.

Comment: You have the option to turn auto-formatting off. Either way, traditional comments are really going to be the only option here. Trust me, comments go a long way. I currently have to maintain an application that is 15 years old in a 43000 line single code file and it has almost no comments what-so-ever. Debugging has literally been "Changing stuff and seeing what happens.".

Comment: I would remove the comment for the `restore` part as that's redundant and would rather comment on *why* the directive is there instead of describing what it does. Also,  IMO this would not clutter the code any more than any other comment. Yes, the indentation is unlucky maybe making the comment on the same line as the directive could work for you?

Comment: @Freggar damn :D This is actually an idea ... now I feel dumb, tanks ^^