# Why is the compiler saying a field is never used when it is?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2003

Pursuing perfection so as to catch beaudaciousness (paraphrasing Vince Lombardi), I tried to rid a project of its sole warning, which was:
*c:\project\nrps\PoisonFoot\releases\6-4-0\hhs\frmPlatypus.cs(103,16): warning CS0169: The private field 'PDQClient.frmPlatypus.scanned' is never used*

So I commented out that line:

```
private bool scanned = false;
```

...but then I got:

*C:\Project\nrps\PoisonFoot\Releases\6-4-0\HHS\frmPlatypus.cs(3390): The name 'scanned' does not exist in the class or namespace 'PDQClient.frmPlatypus'*

...in two places (in the same class where it's supposedly unnecessarily defined)

How was I able to hoodwink the compiler without even trying? How can I get rid of the warning without receiving an err?

Comment: What places in code caused second error?

Comment: Are you using #if maybe?

Comment: _"Pursuing perfection ..."_ so upgrade your Visual Studio version... you're 10 years behind. `:)`

Comment: -Show- Read the lines where the compiler complains. `scanned` is assigned there, but never read again.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Suppressing "is never used" and "is never assigned to" warnings in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3820985/suppressing-is-never-used-and-is-never-assigned-to-warnings-in-c-sharp)

Comment: If only I could - we are stuck in the "cave man days" here...

Comment: Woe on those super-fast close voters. There __was__ enough information to find the answer, and I learned from it!!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

When `csc`(the C# compiler) says a field is never used, what it actually means is that you never read from the field. If you only write to a private member field the compiler deduces that the field is redundant. So, I'm gonna assume that in line 3390 of `frmPlatypus.cs` you are assigning to scanned, not reading from it, and that's why the compiler complains.

Also - line 3390? Really?

Comment: +1 for _"Also - line 3390? Really?"_. BTW, I have seen worst...

Comment: Not "redundant" but irrelevant. Its assignment might even be missing from the IL.

Comment: What do you mean by "line 3390? Really?" I've worked on files with orders of magnitude more lines than that. In fact, I've seen METHODS with that many lines (and I've never seen the healthcare.gov code).

Comment: I got rid of ALL the code referencing that field - in one place it was assigned "true" and in another place "false" but those states never had any effect on anything else.

Comment: Looks like it's a form class based on the name, if he's using the Form Designer, 3390 lines is not actually that many...

Comment: Yeah, cats here write 3390 LOC before breakfast.