# Visual studio warning: x is never assigned to

Tags: c#

I have the following chunk of code which is using the [?? Operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx) for initialization:

```
    private string _name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name ?? string.Empty; }
    }
```

I guess that this code is valid since it works, however I get the following warning in my error list:

> '_name' is never assigned to, and will always have its default value null

Is there a way to make `Visual Studio` stop warning about this?

Comment: There might be an option in VS to disable the warning, but you could also do `private string _name = "";`.

Comment: The `??` operator never initialises anything, and the documentation you link to does not claim it does.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there a way to make Visual Studio stop warning about this?

The best way would be to understand the warning and **fix the bug that it indicates**.

If you never assign to `_name` this means that reading from `_name` will always return `null`. Is that really what you intend?

[You can also suppress this warning.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3820985/suppressing-is-never-used-and-is-never-assigned-to-warnings-in-c-sharp)

Also note, that `??` simply computes a new value from its operands. It does not assign a new value to anything.

Comment: What bug? if I'm not mistaken this warning has 2 part in it: 1) `'_name' is never assigned to` which is incorrect since there can't be a case where it won't be assigned to. 2) `and will always have its default value null` also not true for the same reasons I mentioned above

Comment: Where are you assigning to it? Not in the code shown. Maybe you assume that `??` writes to `_name` since you call that "*initialization*"? That is not so. I should have picked up on that word immediately and corrected it.

Comment: In the code snippet you posted, `_name` most definitely is never assigned to.  Your property is a read only property that returns the value of `_name` or null if it is null.  The getter doesn't assign anything.

Comment: @Yoav Simply inspect the value of `_name` after reading the `Name` property to verify that `??` does not change it.

Comment: +1 for this: "The best way would be to understand the warning and fix the bug that it indicates.".  Warnings are there for a reason.

Comment: While in this specific case he might be doing it incorrectly, as a matter of fact, Visual Studio brings up this warning if you don't assign a value to the variable in the "sequential" code. For example, if you declare a variable without assigning a value, and then use an if-else block and assign some value to it in both `if` and `else` bodies, VS will still bring up this warning. This is unlike the case of "Function doesn't return a value" warning, which check all execution paths.

Comment: @dotNET not in my testing: `string s;
            if (Environment.TickCount == 0) s = "";
            else s = "s";
            Console.WriteLine(s);`

Comment: @dotNET Not only that, the warning you're talking about is a different warning from the one the OP is getting.

Answer (score 3):

Init _name explicitly:

```
 private string _name = null;
```

Or

```
private string _name = String.Empty;
```

And then you won't have any warning....