# Variable assigned but never used

Tags: c#

```
int price;

    if (listBox1.Text == "Regular McYum")   
        {
           price = 70;
        }
```

How come the 'price' variable is assigned but never used?

Comment: See int price; I used it inside my if statement but still it says that the variable is assigned but never used?

Comment: It is really never being used **after** assignment in code fragment you've posted.

Comment: `price = 70` is an assignment not a use.  A use would be `var d = price * 2;`

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30658839/variable-is-assigned-but-its-value-is-never-used

Comment: Add `Console.Write(price);`, voilà, you have used it

Answer (score 0):

The warning is just clear: *assigning* a variable and *using* it are different things. The first is you set a value to it, the second ones means you´re *doing* something with that value.

So in your case you should pass your variable to a method for example:

```
Console.WriteLine(price);
```

This should be a warning from your compiler, so you can - although you shouldn´t - ignore this.

Answer (score -1):

If `listBox1.Text` does not equal "Regular McYum", then `price` will never get set. You need to ensure that `price` will receive a value on all of the possible code paths.

Comment: It will default to 0 and that has nothing to do with the fact that it's never used, which means the value is read not written.  `price = 70;` is not a use, it's an assignment.

Comment: That's not what the warning is saying. The warning is saying that `price` is given a value (`price = 70;`) but the code does nothing with that value. It's similar to a completely un-used variable, except there is an assignment performed.