# How can I "use" a variable to stop an error message saying it's not used?

Tags: c#

My IDE is always opening up and giving me this message:

```
try
{
   await Task.Delay(1000, App.tokenSource2.Token);
}
catch (TaskCanceledException ex) { ex = null; }
```

> The variable ex is declared but never used.

I would like to avoid being the message.  Any suggestions?

Comment: You can disable the pragma warning - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3820985/suppressing-is-never-used-and-is-never-assigned-to-warnings-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just dont specify any variable if you are not planning to use it:

```
try
{
   await Task.Delay(1000, App.tokenSource2.Token);
}
catch (TaskCanceledException) { ... }
```

Comment: he might want it to breakpoint and look into it in the debugger

Comment: In the debugger you can always check exception via locals window or just add $exception in watch list.