# Warning warns about a fixed issue without adding more code

Tags: c#, warnings

[image]

This is quite annoying. Any idea on how to fix this without the #pragma code?

EDIT: You just have to restart visual studio and it'll work...

Comment: Have you tried to clean up solution and rebuild?

Comment: sometimes it's just VS issue. Try to restart Visual Studio and rebuild solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Suppressing "is never used" and "is never assigned to" warnings in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3820985/suppressing-is-never-used-and-is-never-assigned-to-warnings-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was as simple as restarting visual studio... Who would've thought...