# What is visual studio equivalent of GCC attribute unused

Tags: c++, gcc

What is the visual studio equivalent of this line in gcc.

```
 bool box_is_inside(TerBox* box, glm::vec3& p) __attribute__((unused));
```

Comment: If possible, please use [standard C++ attributes](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes), like [`[[maybe_unused]]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes/maybe_unused).

Comment: MSVC, in newer versions, supports `[[maybe_unused]]` ([docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/attributes?view=msvc-170))

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Visual Studio equivelent of gcc \_\_attribute\_\_((unused)) in c++11 (or lower)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52058457/visual-studio-equivelent-of-gcc-attribute-unused-in-c11-or-lower), https://stackoverflow.com/a/52066370/421195